# django urls without a trailing slash show Page not found

Tags: python, django

in django urls without a trailing slash in the end i get this result "Page not found 404"
the same project and the same code in one pc i get different result.
this code is when i get the page without slash:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('about', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

and this the same code but i should to add slash

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

what i am waiting in the frontend its my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def about(request):
return HttpResponse('about page')
```

i am waiting for your help guys

Comment: If the url path in `urls.py` ends with a slash, then you should put a slash on the end in your browser.  If it doesn't, then don't.  What is your actual question?

Comment: i don't understand why in the same code i got different results ? and i wanna to add it on urls.py without slash

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is controlled by the `APPEND_SLASH` setting. In the default setting [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) is set to `True` which means if the requested URL does not match any paths set in `urls.py` an HTTP redirect will issue to the same URL with a trailing slash.

Eg:
Assume a request to `/foo.com/bar` will redirect to `/foo.com/bar/` in case the provided URL `/foo.com/bar` is an invalid URL pattern.

Documentation states that

> Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.

> The `APPEND_SLASH` setting is only used if [`CommonMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common) is installed (see Middleware). See also `PREPEND_WWW`.

please read the documentation for further clarification.

Comment: you have solution i already add APPEND_SLASH on settings.py and nothing